# Python - Regex, multiple match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a file which conatains amongst others SQL-CREATE-TABLE-commands.
I want to write all SQL-CREATE-TABLE-commands into a list (not implemented yet), each command in a seperate list entry.

My problem is, that the regular expression does only return the first match, but there should be more.

Source file:

```
abcd
something
CREATE TABLE schema.test1(attribute1 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE2 DECIMAL(28, 7)  KEY  NOT NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE3 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NOT NULL , 
SET("db_alias_name" = 'TEST')
;

efgh
something else
CREATE TABLE schema.test2(attribute1 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE2 DECIMAL(28, 7)  KEY  NOT NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE3 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NOT NULL , 
SET("db_alias_name" = 'TEST')
;

something else
CREATE TABLE schema.test3(attribute1 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE2 DECIMAL(28, 7)  KEY  NOT NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE3 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NOT NULL , 
SET("db_alias_name" = 'TEST')
;
something else
12346
higkl
```

My script only returns the first match:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.test1(attribute1 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE2 DECIMAL(28, 7)  KEY  NOT NULL , 
ATTRIBUTE3 DECIMAL(28, 7)  NOT NULL , 
SET("db_alias_name" = 'TEST')
```

Script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import re

create_table_parts = []

atlfile = 'example.txt'
data = ''

def read_file(afile):
    with open(afile) as atl:
        text = atl.read()
        return text

data = read_file(atlfile)
data_utf8 = unicode(data, "utf-8")

round1 = re.search(r"(CREATE\sTABLE).+?(?=;)", data_utf8, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
print round1.group()
```

Could you maybe tell me, what's wrong here?

Comment: You might benefit from using a parser instead of relying on regular expressions. https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be better off using [finditer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) because it returns a `match` object like `search`:

```
someIter = re.finditer(r"(CREATE\sTABLE).+?(?=;)", data_utf8, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
for mObj in someIter:
    # process mObj
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `findall` instead, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall

Comment: For some reason the postive lookahead isn't working with re.findall , it returns only the first part of the regex:

print re.findall(r"(CREATE\sTABLE).+?(?=;)", data_utf8, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

Returns:

[u'CREATE TABLE', u'CREATE TABLE', u'CREATE TABLE']

Comment: Just use this regex instead `'CREATE\sTABLE.+?(?=;)'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark's hint, below now a working example solution:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import re

create_table_parts = []
atlfile = 'example.txt'
data = ''

def read_file(afile):
    with open(afile) as atl:
        text = atl.read()
        return text

data = read_file(atlfile)
data_utf8 = unicode(data, "utf-8")


def round1_get_CT(text):
    match_list = []
    someIter = re.finditer(r"(CREATE\sTABLE).+?(?=;)", text, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    for mObj in someIter:
        #print mObj.group()
        match_list.append(mObj.group())
    return match_list

create_table_parts = round1_get_CT(data_utf8)

print "\n".join(create_table_parts)
```